# Create a typescript function returning react component class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to create an utility function, which will be returning one of react component classes (not instances) depending on some condition. So the return type of the function should be generic (React.PureComponent)

```js
import React from 'react';
class FooOne extends React.PureComponent {
    render(): React.ReactElement {
        return null;
    }
}
class FooTwo extends React.PureComponent {
    render(): React.ReactElement {
        return null;
    }
}
function getFooClass(condition: boolean): typeof React.PureComponent {
    return condition ? FooOne : FooTwo;
}
const SomeFooClass = getFooClass(true);
const instance: React.PureComponent = new SomeFooClass();
```

code above is tended to be working (I still not understand why I need to use **typeof React.PureComponent** as return type for getFooClass, this was found experimentally), 
but typescript generates the following error for getFooClass:

```
Type 'typeof FooOne' is not assignable to type 'typeof PureComponent'.
  Construct signature return types 'FooOne' and 'PureComponent<P, S>' are incompatible.
    The types of 'props' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<P>'.
        Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<P>'.
```

Maybe this is kind of typescript bug or limitation?

Comment: Which version of typescript you're using? [This works...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoNAGxQGda4AxCCAeQDsk4kAPGJdgBMGydDAB0ABQCuRAMK5IndvADe5OJrhEhSKAAoAlAC5ExCaIwBRKkhAD4AHzjtpVKnHVbv2pDFnsLm5UFN4AvuQR1HQMzBAAKgDuENx8AsJmYlKySArgEMpqGlo6gnpGppYW5jZ2DnDOru6exT6+-lCBTSGtcBERmNLsGMAFcADmfnFyNPT6aAWCwDCj7KYARiy2KOwmcDAAnmBIEJiZGNnyigX1XiV+AXALQsurcAD8TCwcXKZxSRAKFECrR4ABlXBIaazBgAXgmUxYMxi+hgUGkSEMFGeoLgwHYoJ2aCQlXMl1y10KcHhnEScAh9mhKNUYSxQA)

Comment: Regarding `typeof` - it is required to indicate that you're returning constructor and not an instance. 
Btw, why would you need to instanciate the component manually with `new SomeFooClass..`? Just curious

Comment: @AlekseyL., new SomeFooClass really looks weird, this is actually bad example. 
how its really used:
`class AnotherComponent extends Component {
    const GenericEditor = getFooClass(this.state.condition);
    render() {
        return <div><GenericEditor /></div>
    }
}`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Its really weird, but my example is actually compiling well in playground (besides of absence a null in return type). Typescript version is the same -3.7.5. 
Probably is connected with some specific tsconfig settings.. For my case I cound a workaround. Need to declare class as `class FooTwo<P, S> extends React.PureComponent<P, S> {}`

Comment: Render return type should be `React.ReactNode` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoNAGxQGda4AxCCAeQDsk4kAPGJdgBMGydDAB0ABQCuRAMK5IndvADe5OJrhEhSKAAoAlAC5ExCaIwA5CIK7qtj7Uhiz2cdtKpUKjgL7kAdR0DMwQACoA7hDcfALCZmJSskgK4BDKahpaOnYGJokY4pYwNnZwDk6aRK5Q7p7evloBAeSY0uwYwBlwAOYuYXI09PpoGYLAMN3spgBGLFSo7AUwAJ5gSBCYhRIy8ooZAlmONW5wY0KT03AA-EwsHFymYVEQFK3tnVM9-TCDw7QAEyjcZXDJzBZLAolcRpJRHcLrezZaouM4XCbfdx3MKPODPFivd7kSgZWjwcJIclwAC8cCMtIAfBUUecyfA4QBGWl9AYsIYhfQwKDSJCGJqaC7UuGAnm-f4hYGYFBUWhiiXOWruAA8jO1XLgAHo9TKjXrje8gA)

Comment: Anyway better to use more generic `React.ComponentType` when function returns some component (not an instance) -  `function getFooClass(condition: boolean): React.ComponentType`

Comment: AlekseyL., Another assumption, that my problem caused by bug in @types/react. You are using react 16 in your examples in playground, while my project is on legacy react version 15 and old @types package correspondingly.

Comment: @AlekseyL., thank you for all explanations! `React.ComponentType` is exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
function getFooClass(condition: boolean): React.ComponentType {
   // if FooOne and FooTwo have arguments you can use React.ComponentType<TArgs>
   return condition ? FooOne : FooTwo;
}
```

usage should be like this

```js
function render() {
    const FooEl = getFooClass(true); // PascalCase is required
    return <FooEl />
}
```

or simply return created instance

```js
function getFooClass(condition: boolean): JSX.Element  {
   return condition ? <FooOne /> : <FooTwo />;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

React.ReactNode should work in this case:

```
function getFooClass(condition: boolean): React.ReactNode {
  return condition ? FooOne : FooTwo;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, `React.ComponentType` should be used. But even with `React.ComponentType`, `new SomeFooClass()` won't be allowed

Comment: Sorry.. I see that now :/

Comment: @AlekseyL. using React.ReactNode will compile

Comment: answer updated - this is a great resource for react TS things https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet

Comment: Now it's completely wrong, `React.ReactNode` is result of render, not a type of component https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L202